# Exclude all values <1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

From a dataset I am attempting to return a simple table where it excludes all the values <1.

I searched through https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#aggfunctions for the command but could not find any to fit the description.

[image: I got this so far]

What command do I add where to get the result I need?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please try to get started using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead if you can. This is the dialect that is in active development by the BigQuery team and whatever you learn will generally transfer to other engines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WHERE clause between FROM and ORDER BY

e.g.

```
Select date, campagne, clicks
from `[dataset].[table]`
where clicks >1
order by clicks
```

Comment: should be `where clicks >= 1` :o)